# What does it mean when a chord in the bass-clef bar is marked with a treble clef and what is the extent of applying that notation.This is piano music

Tags: notation, clefs

There is a treble clef next to a chord in the bass-clef bar near the end of a piece of music I'm trying to learn.  I don't know how to interpret it.  Should I play just this one chord as if it were on a treble-clef staff?  All notes in that measure? All notes for left hand (piano music) until the end of the piece?  This notation has me baffled.  I have not been able to find a similar example or question online.  I hope someone can help.

Comment: Hi, welcome to MP&T! I would suggest an image of what is exactly puzzling you. As described, it seems that this should be played as if it were on the treble clef but hard to know for sure!

Comment: If you can't for whatever reason post an image, tell us the name of the piece.

Answer (score 4):

The treble clef persists until cancelled by a bass clef.  You say your example happens 'near the end' of a piece.  So quite likely the treble clef continues to the end.

Though the upper stave conventionally gets a treble clef, the lower a bass clef, this is by no means inevitable and temporary changes are commonplace.  It happens three times in the first couple of lines of this sonata!  The lower stave starts conventionally in bass clef, changes to treble for just three notes,  then back to bass.  See?

[image]